# Nikon D3100 not taking pictures

Tags: blur

My Nikon D3100 not taking pictures when its switch to "A" mode of 18-55mm lens, but it take pictures when it's to "M" mode of 18-55 lens, but zoom in is very blur its clear in zoom out?

Comment: what do you mean by "not taking picture in A mode" ? Is it not able to focus or camera is focusing but not clicking pictures ? Provide more information. In "M mode" see if the auto focus is set to manual. My guess it was set to manual focus after focusing at 18mm that's why u get clear pictures at 18mm and not at 55mm.

Comment: It sounds like autofocus is disabled either on the lens or body (or both) and the setting to wait for focus before taking the picture is enabled.

Comment: What happens when you set to Av (aperture priority) or Tv (shutter priority) modes? Have you tried a different lens? What focus settings have you set?

Answer (score -3):

I had this issue with my D3100. The solution is on my page https://www.facebook.com/zenflautistphotography/posts/401997903505553:0

Comment: Please include the solution in this answer, rather than linking to an external site. Link-only answers are liable to be deleted.